# Border color doesn't work in Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, storybook

I need to write some button component in Storybook with Tailwind CSS (and I'm completely new for both Storybook and Tailwind). I need to change the border color of some button to gray-800. I have both `border` and `border-gray-800` classes but still get the `rgb(0,0,0)` in the computed styles for the element.

This is a full className of the button: `"inline-flex justify-between items-center h-10 w-max p-1 pl-4 border border-gray-800 rounded-full"`. Any other styles are applyed perfectly. What can be the problem?

Maybe I have first to enable this color someway in the tailwind config or something like this?

Thanks!

Update: I also noticed that the right color is also not applied to the text when I use "text-gray-800".

By the way, the editor also doesn't show the contents of this class on hover.

Comment: did you inspect it in your browser inspector?  is it possibly being overridden?

Comment: In the inspector I see all these classes like .inline-flex, .justify-between, .h-10, etc. But the .border-gray-800 doesn't appear there although it exists in tailwind as you can see on this page:

https://tailwind.build/classes/border-color/border-gray-800

Comment: Please show us your `tailwind.config.js` as you may override default colors

Comment: module.exports = {
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class',
  theme: {
    colors: {
      'rhombus-green': {
        DEFAULT: '#24D5D6',
        dark: '#00A1A7'
      },

    },
  },
}

sorry, I don't know how to make this code formatted here

Comment: OK, after I removed `colors {...}` from the config, I see the tailwind colors do work. So the question now how do I need to config my custom colors without breaking the default styles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're overriding default Tailwind colors by putting your colors directly into `theme.colors`. If you want to have both your custom colors and Tailwind you need to [extend](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#extending-the-defaults) them

```
module.exports = { 
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'], 
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class', 
  theme: {
    extend: {
       colors: { 'rhombus-green': { DEFAULT: '#24D5D6', dark: '#00A1A7' } }, 
    },
  }, 
}
```

That approach is valid for every Tailwind property except maybe breakpoints